# Controller Spawner couldn't find the expected controller_manager ROS interface

Tags: ros, ros-control, gazebo-ros-control, controller-manager

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using moveit with spiri_simulator package. When I launch  the file, I get the warning, "Controller Spawner couldn't find the expected controller_manager ROS interface". I cut the ros_control and gazebo_ros_pkgs and paste it back in the catkin workspace. Sometimes this solves the problem but at most times this does not solve the problem. I don't find this problem with controller_manager while using other simulators. What should I be doing?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/218373/controller-spawner-couldn%27t-find-the-expected-controller_manager-ros-interface./) by [boon](https://answers.ros.org/users/21540/boon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2015-09-28

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [boon](https://answers.ros.org/users/21540/boon/) on 2015-10-01**:
Creating a separate launch file for the node, 'controller_spawner' and launching it after the simulator and Rviz ( I was using for visualization) were launched, solved the problem. Was the node missing some information before, that it could not be launched?

**Comment by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) on 2015-10-01**:
The spawner only **requests** controller load and start actions. They are **serviced** by the `controller_manager`. The error you are getting is telling you that the spawner did not find a running `controller_manager` in its namespace to service its requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Make sure the namespace is same in the gazebo plugin and the controllers.yaml file. This namespace is equal to the name of the robot in your URDF file. Also make sure the hardwareInterface type (eg. PositonJointInterface) matches the corresponding controller of the joint in controllers.yaml file you created.

For eg. my gazebo plugin has this tag:  /arm_mesh

where arm_mesh is the name specified in my URDF.

My controllers.yaml file is like this:

```
arm_mesh:

  robotic_arm_controller:

      type: "position_controllers/JointTrajectoryController"

         .......
```

My launch file to activate controller manager:

```
 <launch>

   <rosparam file="$(find PKG_NAME)/config/controllers.yaml" command="load"/>

      <node name="robotic_arm_controller_spawner" pkg="controller_manager" type="spawner" 
        respawn="false"  output="screen" ns="/arm_mesh" args="robotic_arm_controller"/>


 </launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [Sohan_Anisetty](https://answers.ros.org/users/43640/sohan_anisetty/) with karma: 26 on 2019-07-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1